# Android Studio ListView onClick

Tags: onclick

I am sorry if my question seems too easy to know, but I am new to android and I do not know what i am doing wrong. I tried finding the solution to this on the net but could not come up with any solution. I also tried different methods. Please help me understand where I am going wrong. My app stops suddenly when I am trying an onClick event for listview(which I am printing in a textView)
here is my code, 
content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".SqlLiteActivity">

   <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

SqlLiteActivity.java

```
public class SqlLiteActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//Printing a list
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        List<Music> datadisplay = db.getAllMusic();
        ArrayAdapter<Music> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Music>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, datadisplay);
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextView);
        String mystring = getResources().getString(R.string.mystring);
        tv.setText(mystring);

    }
```

Log:

```
      10-29 18:23:58.196 15536-15536/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
10-29 18:23:58.196 15536-15536/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
10-29 18:23:58.581 3064-3519/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:23:59.336 3064-3259/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:23:59.336 3064-3259/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:23:59.346 3064-3259/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:00.516 3064-3074/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:00.521 3064-3074/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:00.526 3064-3074/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:01.446 3064-3404/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 3600
10-29 18:24:05.661 3064-3572/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:05.666 3064-3559/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:06.151 3064-3491/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:06.256 3064-3556/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:06.331 3064-3490/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:06.441 3064-3467/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:06.551 3064-3572/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:06.706 3064-3490/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:06.856 3064-3607/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:06.951 3064-3328/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:06.961 3064-3074/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:07.636 3064-3538/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:07.786 3064-3543/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:08.031 3064-3607/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:08.206 3064-3607/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:08.451 3064-3543/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:08.641 3064-3538/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:09.021 3064-3573/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:09.191 3064-3074/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:09.191 3064-3543/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:09.321 3064-3491/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:09.401 15648-15648/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
10-29 18:24:09.401 15648-15648/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
10-29 18:24:09.486 3064-3607/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:09.696 3064-3466/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:09.891 3064-3259/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:10.061 3064-3490/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:10.061 3064-3074/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:10.351 3064-3556/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:10.546 3064-3466/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:10.546 3064-3328/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:10.546 3064-3328/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:10.551 3064-3328/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:10.836 3064-3328/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:10.836 3064-3328/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:10.841 3064-3328/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2, PID: 15693
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2.SqlLiteActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1965)
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2.SqlLiteActivity.<init>(SqlLiteActivity.java:31)
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2222)
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363) 
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161) 
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265) 
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356) 
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265) 
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081) 
10-29 18:24:11.196 15693-15693/com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
10-29 18:24:11.731 3064-15742/? E/android.os.Debug: !@Dumpstate > sdumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
10-29 18:24:12.576 15634-15708/? E/Fabric: Unknown error while loading Crashlytics settings. Crashes will be cached until settings can be retrieved.
10-29 18:24:12.576 15634-15710/? E/Answers: Failed to retrieve settings
10-29 18:24:13.391 15877-15877/? E/SharedPreferenceProvider: onCreate
10-29 18:24:18.506 3064-3074/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:18.506 3064-3074/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:18.511 3064-3074/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:18.521 3064-3466/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:18.521 3064-3466/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:18.526 3064-3466/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:18.531 3064-3519/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:18.531 3064-3519/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:18.536 3064-3519/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
10-29 18:24:18.736 15912-15912/? E/HealthDataStore: disconnectService : IllegalArgumentException
10-29 18:24:20.606 3064-3194/? E/WindowManager: Starting window AppWindowToken{46766310 token=Token{453b5820 ActivityRecord{43474858 u0 com.example.mayurpitale.bluetoothtrial2/.SqlLiteActivity t577}}} timed out
10-29 18:24:21.326 15947-15947/? E/HealthDataStore: disconnectService : IllegalArgumentException
10-29 18:24:21.446 21561-21561/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid parameter app
10-29 18:24:21.451 21561-21561/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
10-29 18:24:21.616 16069-16081/? E/SPPClientService: ShipBuild Binary : True
10-29 18:24:23.061 15947-16058/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.sec.android.service.health.cp.MigrationCpProvider
10-29 18:24:25.186 16259-16259/? E/ObjectHelper: Can't find method:setCompatibilityInfo
```

Comment: You should be able to use logcat (the built in logging system in Android/Android studio) to see what the error is.

Comment: I did try that as well.

Comment: What was the output? If nothing try putting in a log to see if the method is even being called

Comment: The error in the log is this  [ERROR:get_updates_processor.cc(248)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates
10-29 18:06:01.356 3064-3404/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 3564
1. I am not sure what that means. Is this the reason why the app is not working?

Comment: I highly doubt that that is the error. The class mentioned get_updates_processor.cc is not in your code as far as I can see and does not seem to be related. Modify your question with the full output of the log during the time frame that you are doing the loading of that activity and the clicking of the item.

Comment: Looks like a null exception of some kind I would suspect. You may want to do a toast if v or the view you are trying to find are null

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks like that was the problem. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The list view has something like it's own onClickEvent.  I know this is a bit late but if you're still in need perhaps this can help.

```
// As usual initialize your listview
ListView listview = findViewById(R.id.listviewname);

// The list view has it's own onclick event which goes by the item
// simply set an OnItemClick event.  I hope this is answers your quesiton
// and in if it has, assuming you haven't already found the answer, have a 
// great day.  

listview.setOnItemClick(AdapterView<?>, final View view, final int position, 
long l){

// Code goes here and when you want the system to know which button you 
pressed you simply call the position perimeter.

});
```